# Is it possible for an order 1 ODE to admit only elementary functions as solutions, but cannot be solved?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elementary-functions

Is it possible to find an ODE of order $1$ such that there exist elementary functions as solutions (and no other solutions), but the equation cannot be solved (i.e., the elementary solutions cannot be found from the expression of ODE using any method, except by trial and error)?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you can't find the solutions by "any method," how do you know they exist?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, is it not possible that you can prove the existance of something without actually finding it?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you mean by "find," I guess.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I mean, the elementary solutions exist, but the only way to know what they are is by trial and error (and even so, we can only find them if we are extremely lucky). If trial and error is forbidden, we simply could not solve the equation. Is such scenario possible?